# Nodes with cases in mathematics for tikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, cases

With thanks to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74540/nodes-with-cases-with-tikz), the accepted answer is quite clever:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every left delimiter/.style={xshift=1ex}]
\node (r) {$\vec{r}=\vec{r}(\vec{R},t)$};
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=\lbrace,below = 10pt of r] (mat)
{
x_1 = F(x) \\
\cdots \\
x_1 = F(x) \\
};
\draw[->,shorten >= 6pt] (r.west) -- +(-15pt,0) |- (mat);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to add 'X=' to the left of the large brace. I don't need the arrow. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean you don't need the line with arms, from `r =` to the brace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every left delimiter/.style={xshift=1ex}]
\node (r) {$\vec{r}=\vec{r}(\vec{R},t)$};
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=\lbrace,below = 10pt of r] (mat)
{
x_1 = F(x) \\
\cdots \\
x_1 = F(x) \\
};
%\draw[->,shorten >= 6pt] (r.west) -- +(-15pt,0) |- (mat);

\node [left=5pt of mat,yshift=1pt] {$X=$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not a `cases` with an  `aligned` environments? I also suggest vertical dots inside, rather than horizontal, and centred w.r.t. the left-hand side (`\vdotswithin*` command `from`mathtools`), and the niver looking arrows from`esvect`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[b]{esvect}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
      & \enspace \vv{r}=\vv{r}\bigl(\vv{R\,},t\bigr) \\
  X = &
  \begin{cases}
    \begin{aligned}
      x_1 & = F(x) \\[-1.5ex]
      \shortvdotswithin*{=} & \\[-2ex]
      x_1 & = F(x)
    \end{aligned}
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) I was about to put `\vdots` but it brings me some errors that I could not help. I did not know about `\vdotswithin*`.

Answer (score 2):

But since you are not needing the arrow, you can just wrap the equations into an `array` environment, with no Ti*k*Z involved

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{cc}
      &  \quad\vec{r}=\vec{r}(\vec{R},t) \\[3ex]
  X = &  \left\{
            \begin{aligned}
                x_1 & = F(x) \\
                    & \cdots \\
                x_1 & = F(x)
            \end{aligned}
        \right.
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you heard of `\begin{cases}...\end{cases}`?

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, sure. But I decided to elaborate this one by considering other options.